# Could I add Python2 to AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP platform?

Tags: php, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Now I am trying to upload my PHP app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk with PHP platform.

My PHP executes script.py with Python2,
so I need to install Python2 to Elastic Beanstalk.
What shoud I do at first ?
And where the Python2 would be installed ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to use [`.ebextensions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages) to install Python2.

Basically, your application source code would need to have a `.ebextensions` file with a snippet of the following kind:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    python27-devel.x86_64: []
```

If you environment's operation system is Amazon Linux, perform `yum search python` to determine the set of Python2.7 packages you need and then list them under packages/yum in the above file.